# What does this person mean by: "I want to be thrown free of the accident"?

Tags: american-english, british-english

From this [Stackexchange question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33087/how-is-it-possible-that-it-took-until-the-1950s-or-even-longer-before-they-start/33094#33094):

> In the US, the NHTSA, National Highway Traffic Safety Administration,
>   was formed in 1966. Prior to this there really wasn't a regulatory
>   agency in the US for such things - the world was a much more laissez
>   faire place then. Innovations in safety came from the manufacturers,
>   who noticed and wanted to do something about deaths rates. Volvo
>   introduced the 3-point belt in 1958, but it wasn't until well into the
>   70s that cars came with them standard as part of the default belt.
>   Mercedes pioneered crumple zones. US cars in the 60s often had safety
>   belts as options, not even standard equipment. We had a 1973 Ford that
>   had shoulder belts strapped up in the overhead over the windows and
>   you had to take them down and connect them to use them. They were
>   terrible. No give, so you couldn't even reach the radio.
>
> Old cars were death traps. Anyone who gives their kid a 60s Mustang to
>   drive is giving them a bomb. Gas tanks behind the rear seat, solid
>   steering columns that extended past the front wheelbase, no side
>   impact protection, etc.
>
> It's really the same thing with head restraints and airbags. It took
>   government regulations to make them happen, because people tend to
>   just not care. There was a national outcry about the extra expense of
>   airbags when they were introduced. A car without them would be
>   unthinkable today. It wasn't until the 80s that wearing seat belts
>   even became widespread. ***The popular opinion of the time was, "I
>   want to be thrown free of the accident," a view since proven as wholly
>   terrible.***
>
> Lately, the US Insurance Institute for Highway Safety has led the way
>   for changes. Smaller side windows (protection against SUV side
>   impacts) and larger A pillars (offset frontal crash protection) are
>   the direct result of their tests and manufacturers wanting better
>   rated vehicles.

Huh? "I ***want to be thrown free of the accident***"? I've read this 50+ times now and it just doesn't read as English to me. What could he possibly be referring to?

What does it mean to "be thrown free of" an accident?

Comment: It means: thrown away from the vehicle by the force of the accident, instead of being held in the seat by a safety belt. They were quite controversial, as were helmets for motorcyclists.

Comment: Yes, @Weather Vane explains clearly. And although one might expect '... thrown free of the vehicle as the crash happens' , 'thrown free of the accident' is an acceptable broadened usage. Compare "Before I got free of/from the situation, I ...' where 'situation' is also abstract.

Answer (score 1):

**It means exactly what it says.**

The speakers hopes that when they are in a car accident rather than being 'trapped' by the seatbelt they are thrown out of the vehicle, somehow miraculously avoiding injury in the process.

As the quote says, "a view since proven as wholly terrible".

Answer (score 0):

- **to be thrown free of** something that is holding you
- **to be thrown clear of** something that is holding you [more usual]

It means that vehicle or horse that was holding you, no longer holds you because the blow pushes you away from the vehicle or horse. To be thrown free or clear means: you are ejected by the force of an impact from a position to another another one, onto the ground or into the water. In the case of a horse, it is not the force of an impact, but the force of the horse's throwing you or bucking you off its back or you falling off its back when, for example, it jumps over an obstacle.

> The truck's driver, Yitzhak Ginsburg, 44, who was standing outside his
>   cab while the truck was filling up, was thrown free of the blast. *The
>   New York Times*
>
> The man, whose name has not been revealed, was thrown clear of the
>   vehicle and airlifted to hospital by coastguard helicopter last night
>   after lifeboat crews braved challenging conditions to try to save him.
>   *The Independent*

as seen on [lugwig.guru](https://ludwig.guru/s/to+be+thrown++clear+of)

You can be thrown free or clear of a vehicle (like a truck, car, boat, tractor etc.in an accident) or from a horse.